# Ratchet не работает на боевом сервере

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Поднят простенький веб-чат на ratchet по [инструкции](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world). Чат прекрасно работает на локалке, но на сервере при попытке подключения выдаёт ошибку 403

```
VM3045:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.67.162.12:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Пока подозреваю, что проблема в доступности порта или файла с другой машины, но как это можно исправить?

Comment: У вас ошибка - ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. Если используете SSL, то необходимо писать `wss://..`, а не `ws://..`..ну и соответственно копать в сторону этой проблемы нужно, получается

Comment: @CryEngineV-FlowGraph, wss возвращает 403 ошибку. На самом деле там целый велосипед из nginx и apache.

Comment: Проксирование на Н порт домена..вирт. хост прописали ? У меня после этого по крайней мере все гуд было